# I need to create a query using MySQL and PHP to get a result of two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL and PHP. I have two tables, one to hold all the company names and the other table has only the company name below the user:

```
Table 1
| # | Company name |
--------------------
| 1 | Microsoft    |
| 2 | HP           |
| 3 | Asus         |
| 4 | Apple        |
| 5 | Amazon       |
| 6 | CCN          |

table 2
| # | Company name | User name |
--------------------------------
| 1 | Asus         |   x1      |
| 2 | Apple        |   x1      |
| 3 | HP           |   x2      |
| 4 | Asus         |   x2      |
| 5 | Apple        |   x2      |
```

I need to create a query that achieves the following. First of all the companies are shown which are associated with a specific user (say Asus and Apple for user x1). After that, the remaining companies from table 1 are shown.

For example, the result of the query I'm looking for, for user X1 will display the rows in this way:

```
| # | Company name |
--------------------
| 1 | Asus         |
| 2 | Apple        |
| 3 | Microsoft    |
| 4 | HP           |
| 5 | Amazon       |
| 6 | CCN          |
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: table 2 should use company id from table 1, not duplicate name.

Comment: I wasn't able to make any sense out of this question.

Comment: @jordanm I am still trying to figure this out.

Comment: @BenCarey - That was my first thought, but if you look at his expected output, he is not just joining relationships.

Comment: so you want to get the content of table 1 in the same order as it is, but the entries used in table 2 with user x you want to be displayed at the top of the result... am I right?

Comment: I interpreted this as asking how to return all companies with a certain ordering.  So, a select from `companies`, left join on a subset of `users`, using the value from `users` to determine ordering.  I don't think this is a bad question, just really badly worded.

Comment: Use `left join` to select unique rows from one table then `right join` to select unique rows from second table and then use `union` between both join query to get your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to include all companies, but for a given user, list the companies associated with that user first.  If that's the case, you do not want to use an `INNER JOIN`.

Here's some SQL that should work.  I've provided reasonable table and field names since you didn't give those.  I'm also assuming that you have a reasonably sane table design with no duplicate rows.

```
SELECT c.company_name,

  CASE
    WHEN u.company_name IS NULL THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'Y'
  END AS user_has_company

FROM companies c

LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE user_name = 'x1'
) u
ON u.company_name = c.company_name

ORDER BY user_has_company DESC, c.company_name
```

This query will return an extra column - `user_has_company`.  I'd use that to indicate whether the current user is associated with a given company, but you can ignore it if you want.

Comment: hello sir i still have some miss understanding for the code can you help me again thanks my first table call table1 has 1 field call company_name the second table call table2 has 2 field call company_name and user_name so i did get where the users and companies come from do i need to create them is users is a new table thanks again

Comment: You really should rename your tables to indicate what data they actually contain.  It sounds like if you rename `table1 -> companies` and `table2 -> users` then my query will work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a JOIN Statement to join another in the SELECT-Statement of table1

Quick example:

SELECT * FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1.id = table2.id WHERE table2.username = 'x1'

You'll find everything you need in the Documentation of JOINs.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/left-join-optimization.html

Comment: While this looks like the sane solution, it wouldn't produce his expected output based on the shown input.

Comment: this was just a quick example and not his perfect solution, you can only learn programming by doing programming buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Create your query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT b.companyName FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.companyName = b.companyName WHERE b.userName = 'x1'";
```

Then, using [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), use:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['companyName'];
    echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT company_name FROM table2 ORDER BY user_name ASC
```

In the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) table, using [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code:

```
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT company_name, user_name FROM table2 ORDER BY user_name ASC");
echo "<table>
      <tr><th>Company Name</th><th>username</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['company_name']}</td><td>{$row['user_name']}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after the MySQL query for this then something like this would work

```
SELECT company_name,SUM(IF(user_name='x1',1,0)) as ordering
FROM `table2`
GROUP BY company_name
ORDER BY ordering DESC
```

But you should look at your schema before you go much further. If you have a column (company_name) in one table that refers to another table you should make that column refer to the PRIMARY KEY of the other table, i.e.

```
Table1

| # | company_name |
--------------------
| 1 | microsoft    |
| 2 | hp           |
| 3 | asus         |
| 4 | apple        |
| 5 | amazon       |
| 6 | CCN          |

table2
| # | company_id   | user_name |
--------------------------------
| 1 | 3            |   x1      |
| 2 | 4            |   x1      |
| 3 | 2            |   x2      |
| 4 | 3            |   x2      |
| 5 | 4            |   x2      |
```

This is one of the first things you learn in database design/normalisation. You will need to change your query in this case. Something like this:

```
SELECT company_name,SUM(IF(user_name='x1',1,0)) as ordering
FROM `table1`
    LEFT JOIN `table2` ON table2.company_id=table1.id
GROUP BY company_name
ORDER BY ordering DESC
```

Comment: please can you check that this is the way i write the code SELECT table1.company_name,SUM(IF(table2.user_name='x1',1,0)) as ordering FROM `table2` LEFT JOIN `table1` ON table2.company_id=table1.id GROUP BY table1.company_name ORDER BY ordering DESC but it showing me only the commun row not all row in the table please help again

Comment: @tony My bad, tables were in the wrong order. Try table1 LEFT JOIN table2